# C# splitting large excel file to smaller files

Tags: c#, excel, file, aspose-cells

I want to split one large Excel file to few smaller and **accessible** files.

I already tried to use this code but the files are not accessible:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("path"))
{
    int fileNumber = 0;

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        int count = 0;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("other path" + ++fileNumber + ".xlsx"))
        {
            sw.AutoFlush = true;

            while (!sr.EndOfStream && ++count < 20000)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: arbitrarily splitting a fie into chunks has purpose but what did you expect would be able to read it? excel has a format- if the format isnt valid it wont see it as a file..

Comment: This is like trying to create two sedans out of a lorry, with only a saw.

Comment: It is do able with Aspose.Cells. But Aspose.Cells will read your original Excel file and create new Excel files for every portion or chunk of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files, other than text files, don't work this way. You can't simply cut at a certain point and obtain a working copy.

As for Excel files, you may look into the following tutorial, which illustrates how to automate Excel from C#:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c--net

Basically, what you want to do is open your large Excel file, decide where you want to split it (every n rows, every n sheets and so on), read each portion and write into a newly created xlsx.